# Mockito in REST Webservice

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Basically we used to use Mockito in Junit for testing support. I have tried to use mockito in real application and i was able to us the API successfully.

My requirement is to create a webservice mock and consumer will be able to use my mock service and will be returing data from the mock object. After i develop the service, the same service should return the data from acutal implementation instead of mock service without any code changes

So basically it should work like when consumer calls any service first my application should check whether any acutal implemetation is present and if not, it should go and check for the mock service implemetation.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give that much help without more detail, but...

You could create a web service interface, that contains all the methods you intend to expose. You could then implement that interface with a concrete class to use in the real application. Testing of consumers could then be performed by mocking the web service interface.

```
interface WebService {
    int foo();
}

class RESTWebService implements WebService {
    int foo() { return 1;}
}

class Consumer {
   private WebService webservice;
   public Consumer(WebService webService) {
       this.webService = webService;
   }
}

//Production code
WebService realService = new RESTWebService();
//For testing
WebService testService = mock(WebService.class);

//Spring configuration
<bean id="Consumer" class="Consumer">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="RESTWebService">
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

//Test Spring configuration
<bean id="Consumer" class="Consumer">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="testService">
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="testService" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="WebService"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: This works but only problem is when the real implementation is ready, we need to change the code from testservice to realservice right. But my requirement doesnt allow me to change the code. the same code should work when we put the real implementation. SO it will work like when any service gets called, if real implementation is ready it should choose the same and if not it should pick the mock.

Comment: So it could be like we shall have an interface and 2 implementation class. but priority always should go to the real implementation class. We are using spring in our project. DO we have any sprng or mockito annotations to map the implementations while loading the context?

Comment: @JosephJohny what you are describing is solved via dependency injection. I have added an example Spring configuration file for both production and testing. This way the Consumer code never changes, you just change which version of the WebService you use depending on the environment e.g. test, dev, prod.